# How to make notice while typing less than minimum length in the input in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the bottom border of input to be red in colour when the lengths of value is less than 3 letters and green if more than 3

```js
function pclck1() {
  "use strict";
  var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  if (x.length >= 2) {
    document.getElementById("fname").style.borderBottomColor = "#0d0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("fname").style.borderBottomColor = "#f00";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="fname" type="text" placeholder="Type Here!" onkeypress="pclck1()">
```

It is working while typing,
but after using backspace and delete the letters until the length of the value become 2 or 1 letters or empty the border bottom is still green.

Comment: the keydown event not helping when the input is not empty,
and keyup cant help if the input have more than 1 letter.

Comment: Change `onkeypress="pclck1()"` to `oninput="pclck1()"`

Comment: ... and "greater then or equal to" should just be "greater than" since allowing equality allows lengths of 2.

Comment: The onkeypress event is not fired for all keys (e.g. ALT, CTRL, SHIFT, ESC) in all browsers. To detect only whether the user has pressed a key, use the onkeydown event instead, because it works for all keys.

source : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

I just changed the event `onkeypress` to `onkeyup`. Both are different in a way that, `onkeypress` will work when you press a key. But the `onkeyup` will work when we release a key after pressing

```js
function pclck1() {
    "use strict";
    var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    if (x.length >= 3) {
        document.getElementById("fname").style.borderBottomColor = "#0d0";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("fname").style.borderBottomColor = "#f00";
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="fname" type="text" placeholder="Type Here!" onkeyup="pclck1()">
```

Comment: This cannot be the correct answer, since it fails if the user right-clicks on the input box and chooses "Paste" from the context menu, because `keyup` is never triggered in that case. You want to use the `input` event instead. This code is also sloppy, in the way that it repeats `document.getElementById('"fname")` three times.

Answer (score 1):

> Change onkeypress="pclck1()" to oninput="pclck1()" – NewToJS

It's worked!!

```js
function pclck1() {
    "use strict";
    var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    if (x.length < 3) {
    document.getElementById("fname").style.borderBottomColor = "#f00";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("fname").style.borderBottomColor = "#0d0";
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="fname" type="text" placeholder="Type Here!" oninput="pclck1()">
```

Thank you [NewToJS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4169803/newtojs)

Comment: This is not an answer. It is merely a report that a comment provided an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write any JavaScript at all here.
You can do this in pure CSS, using the [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) pseudo-class together with the `pattern` attribute.

```css
input { border-bottom-color: green; }
input:invalid { border-bottom-color: red; }
```

```html
<input id="fname" type="text" placeholder="Type Here!" pattern=".{3,}" required>
```

Comment: how is coming, that you have new registered?

Comment: Hi @Nina. Yes, I cancelled my account due to a fascist moderator who randomly deleted some Meta posts I cared about. I visit SO now only when I have absolutely nothing else to do, which is rare. Meanwhile, congratulations on your fabulous progress, and I do hope that all the free content you have been contributing at the cost of so many hours of your time does make someone rich soon (it will, just not you).

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry, I missed your @-mention in the above.

Comment: never mind. i read it. i have enough spare time, actually more.